# how to make a continuous stacked bar graph

Tags: matlab

Does someone know how to make a graph similar to this one with matlab?

[image]

To me it seems like a continuous stacked bar plot.

I did not manage to download the same data so I used [other ones](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oi3fbg7e5ffw10k/GDPpercapitaconstant2000US.xlsx?dl=0).

I tried the following code:

```
clear all

filename = 'C:\Users\andre\Desktop\GDPpercapitaconstant2000US.xlsx';
sheet = 'Data';
xlRange = 'AP5:AP259'; %for example

A = xlsread(filename,sheet,xlRange);

A(isnan(A))=[]; %remove NaNs

%create four subsets
A1=A(1:70);
A2=A(71:150);
A3=A(151:180);
A4=A(181:end);


edges=80:200:8000; %bins of the distributions

[n_A1,xout_A1] = histc(A1,edges); %distributions of the first subset
[n_A2,xout_A2] = histc(A2,edges);
[n_A3,xout_A3] = histc(A3,edges);
[n_A4,xout_A4] = histc(A4,edges);

%make stacked bar plot
for ii=1:numel(edges)
    y(ii,:) = [n_A1(ii) n_A2(ii) n_A3(ii) n_A4(ii)];
end

bar(y,'stacked', 'BarWidth', 1)
```

and obtained this:

[image]

It is not so bad.. Maybe with other data it would look nicer... but I was wondering if someone has better ideas. Maybe it is possible to adapt [`fitdist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitdist.html) in a similar way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, define the x axis. If you want it to follow the rules of `bar`, then use:

```
x = 0.5:numel(edges)-0.5;
```

Then use `area(x,y)`, which produces a filled/stacked area plot:

```
area(x,y)
```

And if you want the same colors as the example you posted at the top, define the colormap and call `colormap` as:

```
map = [
    218 96  96
    248 219 138
    253 249 199
    139 217 140
    195 139 217
    246 221 245
    139 153 221]/255;

colormap(map)
```

(It may not be exactly as the one you posted, but I got it quite close I think. Also, not all colors are shown in the result below as there are only 4 parameters, but all colors are defined)

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: @A_C, I fixed the colors for you, in case you want the same as the example you posted.